# Resize individual cells in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd

I would like to typeset diagrams like this

[image]

which can be done with

```tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        A\otimes B\arrow[d,"f", xshift=-3mm]\arrow[d,"g", xshift=3mm] \rar & C\arrow[d,"h"] \\
        X\otimes Y \rar & Z\\
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

but the value `3mm` is highly subjective and changes when you replace A, B etc. with wider or more narrow terms like A_i et cetera.

It seems the more natural solution is to place A and B in separate cells and treat the connector \otimes as an arrow to let tikz-cd sort out the spacing.  But the following puts far too much space around \otimes

```tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        A\arrow[d,"f"] & \otimes & B\arrow[d,"g"] \rar & C\arrow[d,"h"] \\
        X & \otimes & Y \rar & Z\\
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a means to achieve the first diagram with adaptive spacing while perhaps also using the ergonomic nature of the second approach?

Comment: Please note that `minimal` is not for minimal examples. Use `article` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that a good result can be obtained by adding 0.6em to the default column space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
  A\arrow[d,"f"] &[-\dimexpr\pgfmatrixcolumnsep+0.6em\relax]
  \otimes &[-\dimexpr\pgfmatrixcolumnsep+0.6em\relax]
  B\arrow[d,"g"] \arrow[r] &
  C\arrow[d,"h"]
\\
  X &
  \otimes &
  Y \arrow[r] &
  Z
\end{tikzcd}

\hspace*{0.4em}$X\otimes Y$ % for comparison

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great trick.  Replacing A by Z(x^2-y^2) and Y by H_*(\mathbb{RP}^2) for example resizes exactly as I would have wanted.